# Windows Service logon as "Account" use "Account" proxy settings

Tags: windows, proxy, services

I have an application that needs to access the internet. In our domain policy we prohibit internet access, except for some sites via a proxy. When I run the application in the commandline, it succesfully uses the proxy and connects. When the application is started as a Windows Service (using the same windows login account), it is not using the proxy settings that are configured for that account.

The proxy is configured as the default IE proxy for the specific user account (these settings are automatically used by most applications).

How can I make sure the proxy is used my application running as a Windows Service (under either a specific user account or LocalService/NetworkService etc)?

Comment: Have you logged into the "Account" and configured the proxy settings?

Comment: Yes, the proxy settings are configured correctly (and they do work when I log on as "Account").

Comment: [How do I configure proxy settings for LOCAL SYSTEM?](http://serverfault.com/questions/34940/how-do-i-configure-proxy-settings-for-local-system)